# If statement being ignored in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, if-statement

In xcode, when _nice is 0, it still performs [self ifsss]. Why would that be when I clearly state it should say "worked" in the log?

```
   NSLog(@"nice is %@", _nice);

if (_nice != @"0") {
    [self ifsss];
    NSLog(@"Should not have worked %@", _nice);
}
else {
    NSLog(@"worked %@", _nice);
}
```

The NSLog results are below:

1. nice is 22
2. Should not have worked 22

Comment: How is this related to Xcode? Wouldn't be it the same if you used some other IDE? Or no IDE at all just GCC/clang?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `_nice` is an `NSString`, you need to do:

```
if (![_nice isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
```

You can't use basic comparison operators with objects, only basic types like `int` or `float`.

Comment: Thanks! Stack overflow is making me wait 9 minutes to accept.

Comment: Exactly, `==` compares the memory location (pointer?) and `isEqualToString` compares the text

Comment: Thanks! I did not know I had to do this!